# How to change parameter in variation experiment that are not in main?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to set up an parameter variation experiment in AL. I have an agent population and a single agent in the main agent. All parameters are not stored in main but in the embedded agents. The problem I face now is that I can`t see these parameters in the experiment setup window. Is it required that all parameters are defined in main?

Thank you!

Comment: Additionally I would need to know the following: If I have a population of agents. Each agent has different parameters that have been loaded from database. Is there a way to set up an variation experiment that changes the parameter of every agent in the population simultanously. Would it be easier with an variation experiment or would it be better start the simulation several times while using different database entries?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. Please ask this as a separate question, always try to stick to 1 topic here, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, you use "Parameter propagation" as explained in the [AnyLogic help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Finteraction%2FParameter_Propagation.html&resultof=%22%70%61%72%61%6D%65%74%65%72%22%20%22%70%61%72%61%6D%65%74%22%20).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!